# Parallel tangents for an ellipsoid

Tags: conic-sections, plane-curves, tangent-line

I have an ellipsoid with the equation : $$x^2+y^2-\frac {z^2}{6}$$ I want to solve the equation for tangents that parallel with the plane $3x-2y+5z-1$ are.

Comment: Any thoughts on how you might solve this?

Comment: You don’t have any equations there. Moreover, if you did, the first wouldn’t be that of an ellipsoid.